# how to handle a web version of showdialog in C#

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-web-api, modal-dialog

I am trying to accomplish a functionality from windows form in the web api MVC
scenario.Clearly i am trying to execute code in a same Method between 2 different requests.Request 1 btnClick1 start the execution of the Method, send a change to Client to Open a child modal form .Wait for response from the child form(user will do input)
Then the second request will send (from the child form) to execute the remaining piece of code. I don't know is there is a technology to do that today.

example: in windows forms you open a child form via form.ShowDialog()

```
public buttonClick(){
```

var x= 1+2;

```
ShowDialogChild();
```

===wait for response ==

ApplyOnParentForm(What is changed on child);

```
return to Parrent
```

}

=== form child clase

```
  ShowDialogChild(){
```

Do somthing() modified field that will be sent to parent
}

Comment: You may be able to use jQuery UI's Dialog: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/ Be sure to check out the 5 examples on the right.

Comment: The web is stateless so it is a bit more challenging. jqueryui and bootstrap are common options. http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-bootstrap-modals Also take a look at bootbox http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: By the way, I have a form  in memory(server side) for both parent and child. When i send datat from client to server, i retrieve the form in memory and apply my changes.  The client side is working with no issue.
Remember, I have webform1(parent)  in backend . and click open childform1(child).. i send a response back to jqueryUi open modal form. At this point i want to have an Watching event (task or thread) at the button click waiting for response on the childform1. User do some stuff on child modal  (childform1) and post back to server. At his point to resume the remaining code on Parent1

Comment: ANOTHER way: You have a confirmation button on a windows form. It waiting for user reply to continue. Doing the same in the web by keeping indform as abstract meaning in memory only.btnClick () has 3 line of code.
Server say OpenDialog(yes/no) Line 2 of the Method . I send a response to client . Client open Modal with yes or No. User select yes, click OK. Send request back to the sever, to execute the next line (3)